# NSStream delegate not firing errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, tcp, delegates

I'm struggling with an issue with the NSStream Delegate.

My app creates and opens 10 concurrent TCP clients and connects to 10 TCP Servers in devices I am controlling.
I am creating the 10 sockets each with their own unique input and output streams.
They all feed back in to one stream delegate to process the stream events.

I am able to connect and communicate on all 10 sockets without issue.

However when I unplug one or more of my servers my connections on the iPad still show their state as established and a [outputStream status] message returns 2.

I expected the stream to show an error event when the server is disconnected but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Is this me doing something wrong by connecting multiple streams to a single delegate or is there some other more fundamental issue?

an example of my socket creation which sets the delegate:

```
-(void)connectToHub0 {  
    launchflag = 1;  

    NSLog(@"trying to connect to hub 0");  

    /  
    UInt32 port;  
    port = 40000;  

    launchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector (launchTimeOut:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];  

    Hub *currentHub = [Hubs objectAtIndex:0];  

    /  
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;  
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;  
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)currentHub.ipAddress, port, &readStream, &writeStream);  
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;  
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;  

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];  
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];  

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];  
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];  

    [inputStream open];  
    [outputStream open];  
}
```

The delegate is set in my `viewController.m` as:

```
@interface viewController()<NSStreamDelegate>
```

Comment: Where do you read the stream status? Doesn't the disconnection call the NSStreamDelegate `stream:handleEvent:` method (with a specific event (`NSStreamEvent` like `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` or `NSStreamEventErrorOccurred `)?

Comment: That's what I was expecting but its those specific events I'm not seeing, I seem to just get the NSStreamHasSpaceAvailable event.  I won't copy in the whole stream handler as it's quite large because of the parallel connections but i initialise it with : - (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {  
    switch (streamEvent) {  but a breakpoint at the EndEncountered or ErrorOccurred doesn't ever fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour of a TCP socket.  One way to detect this type of disconnection is to use a *keep-alive* packet as part of your network protocol.

See [this interesting article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) for a more detailed answer.

Comment: That clears an awful lot of things up.  Interesting article, many thanks.